# How to prevent inserting value that is greater than to max in number field in html

Tags: javascript, html, forms, numbers, field

I am using number field in html5,

here is my code,

```
<input type="number" class="edit-items" />
```

i set the max of this number field using javascript.

```
element.max = quantity;
element.min = 0;
element.step = 1;
```

If i am using the arrow-up in the number field. Greater value than the max is not possible. But when I tried to insert in the field, greater value than the max is possible.

I would like to prevent it. How?

Comment: Html lets you insert any value but when you hit the submit button it will check the validation and will show a warning and will prevent submit until user corrects the value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like you said input of type `number` will work fine with arrows and not with manual change so try to use `oninput` event to help you control user inputs :

```js
    document.getElementsByClassName('edit-items')[0].oninput = function () {
        var max = parseInt(this.max);

        if (parseInt(this.value) > max) {
            this.value = max; 
        }
    }
```

```html
<input type="number" class="edit-items" max='10'/>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Add an event listner on the input (oninput) :
check it here   : [on change sample](https://jsfiddle.net/v8kmaoe5/1/)

```
function maxValue(){
    var numbers = document.getElementById("numbers");
    console.log(numbers);
    var maxQuantity = 5;

    numbers.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
        if(this.value>maxQuantity) {
            alert("max value reached ! ");
            this.value = maxQuantity;
        }
    })
};
window.onload = maxValue();
```