# I have a textbox and being user I want to allow to enter the number between 0 and 0.3 using html

Tags: javascript, html

I have taken textbox and I just want to enter the digit only and I just want to allow the number between 0 and 0.3. If the user enters digit > 0.3 then it will generate warning.
input range should be  0 – 0.3A•

I tried to provide max and min value in the input body, but it define the range of digits.

```html
<input type= "number" id =" #hardware_tdc_component` + this.data.id + `" 
       class="form-control" 
       style="font-size: 18px !important;" 
       value="` + this.params.Iout / 2 + `" 
       onkeypress = "calculateSum(input)" 
       onkeydown="javascript: return event.keyCode == 69 ? false : true">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent inserting value that is greater than to max in number field in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34577806/how-to-prevent-inserting-value-that-is-greater-than-to-max-in-number-field-in-ht)

Answer (score 0):

Add `keyup` listener to the `input`, get the input `value` and check if it is between `0-3`.

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    if(this.value < 0 || this.value > 0.3) {
        console.log('Entered number is invalid');
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="number">
```

Comment: can we use multiple events in single input field in the html?

Comment: so my question is that can it be possible if i call a function using event and if i written a code in the function, does it work?

Comment: @Chetan - Yes. The above code does the same you want. The second `parameter` to `addEventListener` is the `callback function` which gets executed once the event is occurred.  You can write your code within the callback function